# $VM variable from whole subscription not resource group variable

Tags: powershell, azure

I've been trying to specify and target machines within a resource group which is a vaiable.

The code I have is

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
   [string]$RG

)
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -like "*$rg*"} 
foreach ($rg in $rgs) 
{
$vms = Get-AzureRmVm -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName
    $vms.ForEach({
        $tags = $_.Tags
        $tags['ShutdownSchedule_AllowStop'] = "whatever";
        Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $_.Id -Tag $tags -Force 
  })
}
```

When I run this I get the following

```
The variable '$_' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At line:1 char:41
+ $vms = Get-AzureRmVm -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName
```

However when I hardcode a name for $RG it seems to work.

Confused..

Any pointers please?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are confusing pipeline and `for (x in b)` constuct. you need to do:

```
$vms = Get-AzureRmVm -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName
```

`$_` works inside pipeline, but in for loop you choose what to call the current iteration variable. in your case its `$rg` (`foreach ($rg in $rgs)`)

ps. <strike>did i really type it wrong in that question?</strike> nope, i didnt ;)

Comment: Thanks for that, getting a bit further but no matter what I edit it still points at the same vm. I changed the vm variable.. Am I missing something,.. :(

Comment: well, do you have more than 1 vm in the resource group. does your `$rgs` variable contain more than 1 resource group?

Comment: I’ve got two resource groups in my test env and one has four VMS and the other has one vm, the one vm is always getting the change irrespective of which resource group I put in RG variable .. does that make sense 

Comment: do you have Skype? because the script looks fine (if you fixed this error)

Comment: I do have skyp but it won't connect from here.. proxy issue I'm guessing. I'll have to have a dig around. The script seems to work but only one resource group. Thanks a lot for your help, again  :)

Comment: well, créate a breakpoint and examine the contents of your variables. something like this: `set-psbreakpoint -command set-azurermresource`. run your script after that and when it hits you will get into debugger you can proceed to use `s` to advance in your script and examine the content of variables. or créate a breakpoint on the `vms` variable and examine contents

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that, ran just  `Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -like "*$rg*"}` and it was correct, checked $vm and it was incorrect.  `get-azurermresourcegroup` lists all the correct groups..

Comment: did you fix this? `$rgs = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -like "*$rg*"}`

Comment: Excellent.. that's done it.. that almost makes sense now, thanks again for your help, I'd have been here for days .. :)